# error invalid output extend in zonal statistic

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, error, zonal-statistics

i have a problem with arcmap10.2...i have a dtm(that now has dimension of the pixel 1000) and another raster whit the same resolution with the code of a specific area..what i want to do is calculate for each area the mean altitude..so i know that with the option zonal statistic as a table i can do that..but when i do it i have this error: invalid output extend (error 010092). i tryed the use the default parameters in the environment..but i have the same result..what i should do?

Answer (score 1):

1) Try setting the environment setting to Union.

2) Check both raster are in the same projection in ArcCatalog.

3) Check the "Zone" Raster is integer and has unique zones.

Comment: thank you very much for your suggestions..i tried to use the setting union but i have this error now: this spatial reference objection cannot be defined from the avaliable information..the problem i think is that they are in 2 different coordinate..but when i try to change one for the other one i cannot see them together..they  not overlap..but if i "clear" the coordinates they overlap.

Comment: you need to reproject the data using "project raster" not change it, then it should work.